# Bulma Navbar Color Modifiers are Not Working

Tags: sass, bulma

Adding color modifier classes to Bulma's navbar is supposed to change the background color (as mentioned here:  http://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/#colors).

I find that this is working fine if I use the css version.  But I"m using the sass version and it is not working.

Any idea why not?

Note -- this is also an unanswered issue on Github:  https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/1192

Answer (score 2):

You have to create file like `my-bulma-theme.scss`, then override needed variables or import other `.scss` files with variables and finally, import `bulma` from `node_modules` and include that `my-bulma-theme.scss` in your pages/preprocessor.

For example `my-bulma-theme.scss`:

```
$navbar-background-color: #f0f0f0;
$another-bulma-variable: 14px;

@import './another-style-variables.scss';

@import '../node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass'; // must be the last thing in file
```

Comment: Thanks! That last import was perfect solution for my problem

Answer (score 0):

I updated to version 0.5.2 of Bulma and now it works as it should.